Error this site can't be reached, 127.0.0.1 refused to connect on HTTP/3 in Rust
I am learning to use HTTP/3 in Rust, but I keep getting this error when I open https://127.0.0.1:4433 in the browser.
error this site can't be reached, 127.0.0.1 refused to connect
There are no errors in the compiler. Is it because of the certificate? The problem is I also don't have an SSL certificate, the certificate I'm currently using is self signed with OpenSSL. Does anyone have a valid SSL certificate please try to running my code to see if it works, so I can determine whether the issue is with the certificate or not, since there are no error messages in the compiler. I have activated port 4433 for both TCP and UDP on the firewall. Does anyone know why this is happening? Here is my code.
Cargo.toml :
[package]
name = "http3"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
anyhow = "1.0"
bytes = "1"
futures = "0.3"
h3 = { version = "*", features = ["tracing"] }
h3-quinn = { version = "*", features = ["tracing"] }
h3-webtransport = { version = "*" }
http = "1"
quinn = { version = "0.11", default-features = false, features = [
    "runtime-tokio",
    "rustls",
    "ring",
] }
rcgen = { version = "0.13" }
rustls = { version = "0.23", default-features = false, features = [
    "logging",
    "ring",
    "std",
] }
rustls-native-certs = "0.7"
structopt = "0.3"
tokio = { version = "1.27", features = ["full"] }
tracing = "0.1.37"
tracing-subscriber = { version = "0.3", default-features = false, features = [
    "fmt",
    "ansi",
    "env-filter",
    "time",
    "tracing-log",
] }
octets = "0.3.0"
tracing-tree = { version = "0.3" }
rustls-pemfile = "2.0"

Main.rs :
use std::{net::SocketAddr, path::PathBuf, sync::Arc};
use bytes::Bytes;
use http::{Request, Response, StatusCode};
use rustls::pki_types::{CertificateDer, PrivateKeyDer};
use structopt::StructOpt;
use tokio::{fs::File, io::AsyncReadExt};
use tracing::{error, info, trace_span};
use h3::{error::ErrorLevel, quic::BidiStream, server::RequestStream};
use h3_quinn::quinn::{self, crypto::rustls::QuicServerConfig};

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
#[structopt(name = "server")]
struct Opt {
    #[structopt(
        name = "dir",
        short,
        long,
        help = "Root directory of the files to serve. \
                If omitted, server will respond OK."
    )]
    pub root: Option<PathBuf>,

    #[structopt(
        short,
        long,
        default_value = "127.0.0.1:4433",
        help = "What address:port to listen for new connections"
    )]
    pub listen: SocketAddr,

    #[structopt(flatten)]
    pub certs: Certs,
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub struct Certs {
    #[structopt(
        long,
        short,
        default_value = "cert.pem",
        help = "Certificate for TLS in PEM format. If present, `--key` is mandatory."
    )]
    pub cert: PathBuf,

    #[structopt(
        long,
        short,
        default_value = "key.pem",
        help = "Private key for the certificate in PEM format."
    )]
    pub key: PathBuf,
}

static ALPN: &[u8] = b"h3";

fn load_pem_cert(path: PathBuf) -> Result<Vec<CertificateDer<'static>>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let cert_file = std::fs::File::open(path)?;
    let mut reader = std::io::BufReader::new(cert_file);
    let certs = rustls_pemfile::certs(&mut reader)
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?
        .into_iter()
        .map(CertificateDer::from)
        .collect();
    Ok(certs)
}

fn load_pem_key(path: PathBuf) -> Result<PrivateKeyDer<'static>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let key_file = std::fs::File::open(path.clone())?;
    let mut reader = std::io::BufReader::new(key_file);
    let pkcs8_keys = rustls_pemfile::pkcs8_private_keys(&mut reader)
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?;
    if let Some(key) = pkcs8_keys.into_iter().next() {
        return Ok(PrivateKeyDer::from(key));
    }
    let key_file = std::fs::File::open(path)?;
    let mut reader = std::io::BufReader::new(key_file);
    let rsa_keys = rustls_pemfile::rsa_private_keys(&mut reader)
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?;
    if let Some(key) = rsa_keys.into_iter().next() {
        return Ok(PrivateKeyDer::from(key));
    }
    Err("No valid private key found in PEM file".into())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_env_filter(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::from_default_env())
        .with_span_events(tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::FmtSpan::FULL)
        .with_writer(std::io::stderr)
        .with_max_level(tracing::Level::INFO)
        .init();

    let opt = Opt::from_args();
    let root = if let Some(root) = opt.root {
        if !root.is_dir() {
            return Err(format!("{}: is not a readable directory", root.display()).into());
        } else {
            info!("serving {}", root.display());
            Arc::new(Some(root))
        }
    } else {
        Arc::new(None)
    };

    let Certs { cert, key } = opt.certs;
    let certs = load_pem_cert(cert)?;
    let key = load_pem_key(key)?;

    let mut tls_config = rustls::ServerConfig::builder()
        .with_no_client_auth()
        .with_single_cert(certs, key)?;

    tls_config.max_early_data_size = u32::MAX;
    tls_config.alpn_protocols = vec![ALPN.into()];

    let mut server_config =
        quinn::ServerConfig::with_crypto(Arc::new(QuicServerConfig::try_from(tls_config)?));
    let transport_config = Arc::get_mut(&mut server_config.transport).unwrap();
    transport_config.keep_alive_interval(Some(std::time::Duration::from_secs(5)));

    let endpoint = quinn::Endpoint::server(server_config, opt.listen)?;
    info!("listening on {}", opt.listen);

    while let Some(new_conn) = endpoint.accept().await {
        trace_span!("New connection being attempted");
        let root = root.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            match new_conn.await {
                Ok(conn) => {
                    info!("new connection established from {:?}", conn.remote_address());
                    let mut h3_conn = h3::server::Connection::new(h3_quinn::Connection::new(conn))
                        .await
                        .unwrap();
                    loop {
                        match h3_conn.accept().await {
                            Ok(Some((req, stream))) => {
                                info!("new request: {:#?}", req);
                                let root = root.clone();
                                tokio::spawn(async {
                                    if let Err(e) = handle_request(req, stream, root).await {
                                        error!("handling request failed: {}", e);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            Ok(None) => break,
                            Err(err) => {
                                error!("error on accept {}", err);
                                match err.get_error_level() {
                                    ErrorLevel::ConnectionError => break,
                                    ErrorLevel::StreamError => continue,
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Err(err) => {
                    error!("accepting connection failed: {:?}", err);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    endpoint.wait_idle().await;
    Ok(())
}

async fn handle_request<T>(
    req: Request<()>,
    mut stream: RequestStream<T, Bytes>,
    serve_root: Arc<Option<PathBuf>>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
where
    T: BidiStream<Bytes>,
{
    let mut contents = Vec::new();

    println!("hello dari http 3");

    match req.uri().path() {
        "/" => {
            contents.extend_from_slice(b"Welcome to the root page!");
        }
        "/api/hello" => {
            let json_response = b"{\"message\": \"Hello from API!\"}";
            contents.extend_from_slice(json_response);
            stream.send_response(
                Response::builder()
                    .status(StatusCode::OK)
                    .header("content-type", "application/json")
                    .body(())
                    .unwrap(),
            ).await?;
        }
        path if path.starts_with("/static/") => {
            if let Some(root) = serve_root.as_ref() {
                let file_path = root.join(&path[8..]);
                let mut file = File::open(&file_path).await?;
                file.read_to_end(&mut contents).await?;
            } else {
                contents.extend_from_slice(b"No static file root set.");
            }
        }
        _ => {
            contents.extend_from_slice(b"404 Not Found");
            stream.send_response(
                Response::builder()
                    .status(StatusCode::NOT_FOUND)
                    .header("content-type", "text/plain")
                    .body(())
                    .unwrap(),
            ).await?;
        }
    }

    let contents = Bytes::from(contents);
    stream.send_data(contents).await?;
    stream.finish().await?;
    Ok(())
}


Update: Here are the newest version of the code.
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "http3"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
hyper = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
pretty_env_logger = "0.5"
http-body-util = "0.1"
bytes = "1"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
form_urlencoded = "1"
http = "1"
futures-util = { version = "0.3", default-features = false }
hyper-util = { version = "0.1.10", features = ["tokio", "server", "http1", "http2"] }
rustls = { version="*", features=["ring", "aws-lc-rs"] }
tokio-rustls = "*"
rustls-pemfile = "2"
pki-types = { package = "rustls-pki-types", version = "1" }
h3 = { version="*", features = ["tracing"] }
h3-quinn = { version="*", features = ["tracing"] }
quinn = { version = "0.11", default-features = false, features = [
    "runtime-tokio",
    "rustls",
    "ring",
] }
structopt = "*"
tracing = "0.1.37"
tracing-subscriber = { version = "0.3", default-features = false, features = [
    "fmt",
    "ansi",
    "env-filter",
    "time",
    "tracing-log",
] }

Main.rs
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use bytes::Bytes;
use http_body_util::Full;
use hyper::service::service_fn;
use hyper::{Request, Response};
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use hyper_util::rt::{TokioExecutor, TokioIo};
use pki_types::{CertificateDer, PrivateKeyDer};
use rustls::ServerConfig;
use tokio_rustls::TlsAcceptor;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::io;
use std::fs::File;
use hyper_util::server::conn::auto::Builder;
use http::{Method, StatusCode};
use http_body_util::BodyExt;
use hyper::body::Incoming;
use h3::{error::ErrorLevel, quic::BidiStream, server::RequestStream};
use h3_quinn::quinn::{self, crypto::rustls::QuicServerConfig};
use futures_util::future::join;
use hyper::header::HeaderValue;

fn error(err: String) -> io::Error {
    io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, err)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    pretty_env_logger::init();

    let _ = rustls::crypto::ring::default_provider().install_default();
    let _ = rustls::crypto::aws_lc_rs::default_provider().install_default();

    let certs = load_certs("cert.pem")?;
    let key = load_private_key("key.pem")?;

    let mut server_config = ServerConfig::builder()
        .with_no_client_auth()
        .with_single_cert(certs, key)
        .map_err(|e| error(e.to_string()))?;
    server_config.alpn_protocols = vec![b"h3".to_vec(), b"h2".to_vec(), b"http/1.1".to_vec(), b"http/1.0".to_vec()];
    let tls_acceptor = Arc::new(TlsAcceptor::from(Arc::new(server_config.clone())));

    let service = service_fn(echo);

    let addr1: SocketAddr = ([0, 0, 0, 0], 4433).into();

    let mut h3server_config =
        quinn::ServerConfig::with_crypto(Arc::new(QuicServerConfig::try_from(server_config)?));
    let transport_config = Arc::get_mut(&mut h3server_config.transport).unwrap();
    transport_config.keep_alive_interval(Some(std::time::Duration::from_secs(5)));

    let h3_server = async {
        let endpoint = quinn::Endpoint::server(h3server_config, addr1)?;

        while let Some(new_conn) = endpoint.accept().await {
            println!("New connection being attempted");

            tokio::spawn(async move {
                match new_conn.await {
                    Ok(conn) => {
                        println!("new connection established from {:?}", conn.remote_address());
                        let mut h3_conn = h3::server::Connection::new(h3_quinn::Connection::new(conn))
                            .await
                            .unwrap();
                        loop {
                            match h3_conn.accept().await {
                                Ok(Some((req, stream))) => {
                                    println!("new request: {:#?}", req);
                                    tokio::spawn(async {
                                        if let Err(e) = handle_request(req, stream).await {
                                            println!("handling request failed: {}", e);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                Ok(None) => break,
                                Err(err) => {
                                    println!("error on accept {}", err);
                                    match err.get_error_level() {
                                        ErrorLevel::ConnectionError => break,
                                        ErrorLevel::StreamError => continue,
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Err(err) => {
                        println!("accepting connection failed: {:?}", err);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Ok(())
        Ok::<(), std::io::Error>(())
    };

    let http2_http1_server = async {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind(addr1).await.unwrap();
        loop {
            let (stream, _) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();
            let tls_acceptor2 = tls_acceptor.clone();

            tokio::task::spawn(async move {
                let tls_stream = match tls_acceptor2.accept(stream).await {
                    Ok(tls_stream) => tls_stream,
                    Err(err) => {
                        eprintln!("failed to perform tls handshake: {err:#}");
                        return;
                    }
                };
                if let Err(err) = Builder::new(TokioExecutor::new())
                    .serve_connection(TokioIo::new(tls_stream), service)
                    .await
                {
                    eprintln!("failed to serve connection: {err:#}");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // join(h3_server, http2_http1_server).await?;
    let (result1, _) = join(h3_server, http2_http1_server).await;
    result1?;


    println!("Listening on https://{}", addr1);

    Ok(())
}

fn load_certs(filename: &str) -> io::Result<Vec<CertificateDer<'static>>> {
    let certfile = File::open(filename)
        .map_err(|e| error(format!("failed to open {}: {}", filename, e)))?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(certfile);
    rustls_pemfile::certs(&mut reader).collect()
}

fn load_private_key(filename: &str) -> io::Result<PrivateKeyDer<'static>> {
    let keyfile = File::open(filename)
        .map_err(|e| error(format!("failed to open {}: {}", filename, e)))?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(keyfile);
    rustls_pemfile::private_key(&mut reader).map(|key| key.unwrap())
}

async fn echo(req: Request<Incoming>) -> Result<Response<Full<Bytes>>, hyper::Error> {
    let mut response = Response::new(Full::default());
    match (req.method(), req.uri().path()) {
        (&Method::GET, "/") => {
            response.headers_mut().insert("alt-svc", HeaderValue::from_static("h3=\":4433\"; ma=3600"),);
            *response.body_mut() = Full::from("Try POST /echo\n");
        }
        (&Method::GET, "/echo") => {
            response.headers_mut().insert("alt-svc", HeaderValue::from_static("h3=\":4433\"; ma=3600"),);
            *response.body_mut() = Full::from(
                req.into_body()
                    .collect()
                    .await?
                    .to_bytes(),
            );
        }
        _ => {
            *response.status_mut() = StatusCode::NOT_FOUND;
        }
    };
    Ok(response)
}

async fn handle_request<T>(
    req: Request<()>,
    mut stream: RequestStream<T, Bytes>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
where
    T: BidiStream<Bytes>,
{
    let mut contents = Vec::new();

    println!("hello dari http 3");

    match req.uri().path() {
        "/" => {
            contents.extend_from_slice(b"Welcome to the root page!");
        }
        "/api/hello" => {
            let json_response = b"{\"message\": \"Hello from API!\"}";
            contents.extend_from_slice(json_response);
            stream.send_response(
                Response::builder()
                    .status(StatusCode::OK)
                    .header("content-type", "application/json")
                    .body(())
                    .unwrap(),
            ).await?;
        }
        _ => {
            contents.extend_from_slice(b"404 Not Found");
            stream.send_response(
                Response::builder()
                    .status(StatusCode::NOT_FOUND)
                    .header("content-type", "text/plain")
                    .body(())
                    .unwrap(),
            ).await?;
        }
    }

    let contents = Bytes::from(contents);
    stream.send_data(contents).await?;
    stream.finish().await?;
    Ok(())
}

This is an independent HTTP/3 code, not mixed with HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2, just to check whether the error ERROR connection{remote_addr=127.0.0.1:55940}: http3: connection error: quic transport error: aborted by peer: the connection is being closed abruptly in the absence of any error is caused by something related to HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 eventhough the response data is received successfully (Using Curl). After separating HTTP/3, the error still occurs, so its not due to the HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/3 code, maybe.
Main.rs (The Cargo.toml is the same)
use std::{net::SocketAddr, sync::Arc, time::Duration};
use std::{env, fs, io};

use bytes::Bytes;
use http::{Request, Response, StatusCode};
use rustls::pki_types::{CertificateDer, PrivateKeyDer};
use structopt::StructOpt;
use tracing::{error, info, trace_span};
use std::fs::File;

use h3::{error::ErrorLevel, quic::BidiStream, server::RequestStream};
use h3_quinn::quinn::{self, crypto::rustls::QuicServerConfig, VarInt};

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
#[structopt(name = "server")]
struct Opt {
    #[structopt(
        short,
        long,
        default_value = "0.0.0.0:4433",
        help = "What address:port to listen for new connections"
    )]
    pub listen: SocketAddr,

    #[structopt(flatten)]
    pub certs: Certs,
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub struct Certs {
    #[structopt(
        long,
        short,
        default_value = "cert.pem",
        help = "Certificate for TLS. If present, `--key` is mandatory."
    )]
    pub cert: std::path::PathBuf,

    #[structopt(
        long,
        short,
        default_value = "key.pem",
        help = "Private key for the certificate."
    )]
    pub key: std::path::PathBuf,
}

static ALPN: &[u8] = b"h3";

fn error(err: String) -> io::Error {
    io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, err)
}

fn configure_transport() -> quinn::TransportConfig {
    let mut transport_config = quinn::TransportConfig::default();
    
    // Convert durations to milliseconds for idle timeout
    transport_config.max_idle_timeout(Some(VarInt::from_u32(10_000).into())); // 10 seconds
    transport_config.keep_alive_interval(Some(Duration::from_secs(2)));
    
    // Use VarInt for window sizes
    transport_config.send_window(VarInt::from_u32(8_000_000).into());
    transport_config.receive_window(VarInt::from_u32(8_000_000));
    transport_config.max_concurrent_bidi_streams(VarInt::from_u32(100));
    
    transport_config
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_env_filter(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::from_default_env())
        .with_span_events(tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::FmtSpan::FULL)
        .with_writer(std::io::stderr)
        .with_max_level(tracing::Level::DEBUG)
        .init();

    let opt = Opt::from_args();

    rustls::crypto::ring::default_provider()
        .install_default()
        .expect("Failed to install default crypto provider");

    let cert = load_certs(&opt.certs.cert.to_string_lossy())?;
    let key = load_private_key(&opt.certs.key.to_string_lossy())?;

    let mut server_crypto = rustls::ServerConfig::builder()
        .with_no_client_auth()
        .with_single_cert(cert, key)?;

    server_crypto.alpn_protocols = vec![ALPN.to_vec()];

    let mut server_config = quinn::ServerConfig::with_crypto(Arc::new(QuicServerConfig::try_from(
        server_crypto,
    )?));

    server_config.transport_config(Arc::new(configure_transport()));

    let endpoint = quinn::Endpoint::server(server_config, opt.listen)?;

    info!("listening on {}", opt.listen);

    while let Some(connecting) = endpoint.accept().await {
        info!("accepting connection from {:?}", connecting.remote_address());
        
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            match connecting.await {
                Ok(conn) => {
                    info!(
                        "connection established from {:?}",
                        conn.remote_address()
                    );

                    let h3_conn = match h3::server::Connection::new(h3_quinn::Connection::new(conn)).await {
                        Ok(conn) => conn,
                        Err(e) => {
                            error!("failed to establish HTTP/3 connection: {}", e);
                            return;
                        }
                    };

                    if let Err(e) = handle_connection(h3_conn).await {
                        error!("connection error: {}", e);
                    }
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    error!("connection failed: {}", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    endpoint.wait_idle().await;
    Ok(())
}

async fn handle_connection(
    mut h3_conn: h3::server::Connection<h3_quinn::Connection, Bytes>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    loop {
        match h3_conn.accept().await {
            Ok(Some((req, stream))) => {
                info!("got request: {:?}", req);
                tokio::spawn(async move {
                    if let Err(e) = handle_request(req, stream).await {
                        error!("failed to handle request: {}", e);
                    }
                });
            }
            Ok(None) => {
                info!("connection complete");
                break;
            }
            Err(e) => {
                match e.get_error_level() {
                    ErrorLevel::ConnectionError => {
                        error!("connection error: {}", e);
                        break;
                    }
                    ErrorLevel::StreamError => {
                        error!("stream error: {}", e);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

async fn handle_request<T>(
    req: Request<()>,
    mut stream: RequestStream<T, Bytes>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
where
    T: BidiStream<Bytes>,
{
    info!("handling request: {:?}", req);
    
    let (status, content_type, response_body) = match req.uri().path() {
        "/" => (
            StatusCode::OK,
            "text/html",
            Bytes::from("<h1>Welcome to the root page!</h1>"),
        ),
        "/api/hello" => (
            StatusCode::OK,
            "application/json",
            Bytes::from("{\"message\": \"Hello from API!\"}"),
        ),
        _ => (
            StatusCode::NOT_FOUND,
            "text/plain",
            Bytes::from("404 Not Found"),
        ),
    };

    let response = Response::builder()
        .status(status)
        .header("content-type", content_type)
        .body(())
        .unwrap();

    stream.send_response(response).await?;
    stream.send_data(response_body).await?;
    stream.finish().await?;

    info!("response sent successfully");
    Ok(())
}

fn load_certs(filename: &str) -> io::Result<Vec<CertificateDer<'static>>> {
    let certfile = File::open(filename)
        .map_err(|e| error(format!("failed to open {}: {}", filename, e)))?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(certfile);
    rustls_pemfile::certs(&mut reader).collect()
}

fn load_private_key(filename: &str) -> io::Result<PrivateKeyDer<'static>> {
    let keyfile = File::open(filename)
        .map_err(|e| error(format!("failed to open {}: {}", filename, e)))?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(keyfile);
    rustls_pemfile::private_key(&mut reader).map(|key| key.unwrap())
}


I assume that your browser and the server are on the same host.  'Cos 127.0.0.1 is a host-local IP address.

"I have activated port 4433 for both TCP and UDP on the firewall" ... Hmmm.   See above!  A connection to 127.0.0.1 won't go off-host, so the firewall can't be relevant.  Or more likely ... you shouldn't be using 127.0.0.1 for this!!

To be specific, try listening on 0.0.0.0:4433 for maximum flexibility.

I'm still getting the same error, sir, it still says it can't be reached and refused to connect. If I access it using https://0.0.0.0:4433, the error changes to: 'The webpage at https://0.0.0.0 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.' Is it redirected to localhost? If I access https://127.0.0.1:4433 in browser, the error is like before.

@StephenC Depending on the host platform, the firewall can absolutely be relevant.

OK I guess that is true.  You >could< firewall 127.0.0.1 ... but is seems an odd thing to do.  (Normally you would allocate the "spaces" their own public or private addresses if there was any need for firewalling local host access.)

@Fuji - Are the browser and server running on the same host?   Note that you should >listen< on 0.0.0.0.  Attempting to connect to 0.0.0.0 will never work.  (I can't help thinking that the real problem here is a fundamental misunderstanding of IP addresses and what they actually mean.)

If the browser and the server are on different machines then the browser should be connecting to a public or private IP address of the server.  That is NOT 127.0.0.1 and it is NOT 0.0.0.0.  When you put 127.0.0.1 into a URL means ">>this<< machine" and when you put 0.0.0.0 into a URL, it doesn't mean anything.  (It is not possible to route packets to 0.0.0.0.)

One of the issues you are facing is a lack of HTTP/3 service discovery. TLS ALPN over UDP is insufficient as browsers navigating to https://127.0.0.1:4433 will first establish a TCP connection. You should consider hosting a TCP, HTTP/1.1 and/or HTTP/2 server on TCP port 4433 that adds a Alt-Svc: h3=":4433"; ma=3600 header to each response. Other than that, the TCP server should return identical responses.
You can read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Alt-Svc
https://my.f5.com/manage/s/article/K16240003

If you only need to connect to your server programmatically, you can bypass the need for the above; just don't expect browsers to be able to connect.
Either way, if you need to connect from another host, you should listen on 0.0.0.0:4433 instead of 127.0.0.1:4433.

Is it meant like this, sir? First of all, when there is an incoming request, I need to respond with HTTP/1 or 2 first and including the header Alt-Svc: h3=":4433"; ma=3600 and response content as usual, for example, JSON data. Then, if the browser requests data again while the browser tab is still open, it will use HTTP/3?

@Fuji yes, that sounds about right (although AFAIK the browser is not obligated to use HTTP/3 if it doesn't want to). And keep in mind HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 are TCP only. It's a separate listener, not just a separate protocol.

I've implemented it, sir, but the browser always uses HTTP/1.1 not even HTTP/2. The Alt-Svc: h3=":4433"; ma=3600 header appears in DevTools, but refreshing still results in HTTP/1.1. However, when I check with curl, both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 work fine, in the HTTP/3 section, the response is sent successfully, but I get an error afterward: ERROR connection{remote_addr=127.0.0.1:55940}: http3: connection error: quic transport error: aborted by peer: the connection is being closed abruptly without any error. Is this expected when using curl, or is there an issue with the HTTP/3 code?

@Fuji please update your question with your new code, combining both types of servers, so we can follow along.

I've edited the question, sir.

I just tried to add more error handling and I got this message sir : Failed to establish HTTP/3 connection: aborted by peer: the cryptographic handshake failed: error 46: 199:TLS handshake failure (ENCRYPTION_HANDSHAKE) 46: certificate unknown. But the certificate can be used in http1.1 and 2. Or maybe how I set up the tls above is incorrect sir?
